# error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, render.com

I'm deploying Java Spring Boot Project on Render.com. Here's Dockerfile and errors.
when deploying code, some strange error happened.
I couldn't figure out what happened. Please let me know. Every comment are welcomed.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
COPY --from=build /target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]
```

**Error**

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/28.2-android/guava-28.2-android.jar (2.6 MB at 4.7 MB/s)
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.07 [INFO] Replacing main artifact /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar with repackaged archive, adding nested dependencies in BOOT-INF/.
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [INFO] The original artifact has been renamed to /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar.original
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [INFO] Total time:  18.303 s
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-15T08:20:00Z
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 21.08 [WARNING] The requested profile "prod" could not be activated because it does not exist.
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #11 DONE 21.2s
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #12 [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  #12 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 1tvcyniff9u6m4oki7cytt7fb::xbb9zgmks3mqn1pni9p0gg08s: "/target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar": not found
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  ------
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM   > [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar:
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  ------
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  Dockerfile:5
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  --------------------
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM     3 |     RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM     4 |     FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM     5 | >>> COPY --from=build /target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM     6 |     EXPOSE 8080
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM     7 |     ENTRYPOINT [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  --------------------
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 1tvcyniff9u6m4oki7cytt7fb::xbb9zgmks3mqn1pni9p0gg08s: "/target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar": not found
Aug 15 05:20:00 PM  error: exit status 1
```

[Appended]
My Code is here.
https://github.com/hardreggaecafe/java_spring_boot_sample

Comment: `Replacing main artifact /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar with repackaged archive`, `The original artifact has been renamed to /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar.original`,  `"/target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar": not found` Don't know if its just me, but it kind of looks like you are looking for something that doesnt exist

Comment: Unfortunately your issue is not reproducible because we don't have the source code.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca Oops sorry. I should have put my code. I will update my post later.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I appreciate for your comment. After replaced my code, it works. I'll write the wrap up.

Answer (score 0):

After replaced my Dockerfile like below, it works.

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
COPY --from=build /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar demo.jar # <- changed file name
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]
```